# How To Get Github Omniauth Authentication To Work In Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab

I can't seem to figure out how to get Github authentication working on my Omnibus installation of Gitlab on Ubuntu 12.04.

```
GitLab 7.5.1
GitLab Shell 2.2.0
GitLab API v3
Ruby 2.1.4p265
Rails 4.1.1
```

Here is what my `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` looks like, personal details removed.

```
external_url "http://git.domain.com"
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_from'] = "git@domain.com"
gitlab_rails['gitlab_support_email'] = "sajan@domain.com"

gitlab_rails['omniauth_enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['omniauth_allow_single_sign_on'] = true
gitlab_rails['omniauth_providers'] = [
  {
    "name" => "github",
    "app_id" => "xxxxxxx",
    "app_secret" => "xxxxxxxxxxx",
    "args" => { scope: 'user:email' }
  }
]
```

On the login page, there is no mention of Github or the Github logo below the login form.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sajan dropped into the GitLab IRC and asked about this.

The result was his information is correct, he just needed run the `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` command and restart his GitLab instance.

Comment: This solved the problem for me too. The documentation at `/help/integration/github` needs to be updated because it says `Restart GitLab for the changes to take effect.`. Restarting is not enough it seems.